# PowerPoint VBA "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

Tags: vba, for-loop, variant, type-mismatch

I'm trying to create an interactive PowerPoint (isn't Excel because it needs to be displayed). I'm trying to do some conditional formatting with code.
The ProdArray are all textboxes that I want to colour based on their value compared to another textbox (ProdTarg)

```
Dim ProdArray(0 To 5) As String
Dim Day As Variant
ProdArray(0) = MonProd
ProdArray(1) = TueProd
ProdArray(2) = WedProd
ProdArray(3) = ThuProd
ProdArray(4) = FriProd
ProdArray(5) = SatProd

For Each Day In ProdArray
    If Val(Day) >= Val(ProdTarg) * (Sixth + SixthLim) Then
        Day.BackColor = &HFF00&
        ElseIf Val(Day) < Val(ProdTarg) * (Sixth - SixthLim) Then
        Day.BackColor = &HFF&
        Else
        Day.BackColor = &H80FF&
    End If
Next Day
```

I've got a For Each loop, to make the coding more concise, but I keep getting a type mismatch. 
The If loop inside is based on the following code:

```
If Val(TueProd) >= Val(ProdTarg) * (Sixth + SixthLim) Then
    TueProd.BackColor = &HFF00&
    ElseIf Val(TueProd) < Val(ProdTarg) * (Sixth - SixthLim) Then
    TueProd.BackColor = &HFF&
    Else
    TueProd.BackColor = &H80FF&
End If
```

I hope this gives you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I hope I've not been too dense, but I can't seem to find a topic on how to integrate the variable in the way I require.

Comment: this code is for UserForm? What is your variables `Day` and `DayArray`? How do you define them? Which line is your error?

Comment: Hi KazJAw, this code is for a Button1_Click. My error is coming from within the For loop - it highlights the line 'For Each Day In DayArray'. So, I assume it is caused by trying to use the value of the variant.

Comment: we don't know what is your `Day` and `DayArray` as you didn't show the appropriate portion of code. So, how could we help you then?

Comment: Hi @KazJaw, the `Day` and `DayArray` are at the top of the first code box - is this not what you need?

Comment: I can't see, there is `ProdArray` not `DayArray` :(

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! That was an error, I changed the name from `DayArray` to `ProdArray` - it now reads `ProdArray`

Comment: and what is now? which error and where you have?

Comment: At the moment there is no "Type mismatch", but now I receive "Object required" at the line `Day.BackColor = `. How can I convert the Variant into an Object?

Comment: to make it clear- `MonProd`, `TueProd` are your TextBoxes in UserForm?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, they are TextBoxes on a presentation slide

Comment: see my answer- hope it will help...

Comment: plus some improvements just added to the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code working you need to do the following changes:

1. declare ProdArray as Variant in this way:

   `Dim ProdArray(0 To 5)`
2. use `Set` to create array element like:

   `Set ProdArray(0) = MonProd`
   `Set ProdArray(1) = TueProd`
   `'etc`

Comment: I'm still having problems regarding an "Object required" error, pointing to the `Set ProdArray(0) =` part...

Comment: have you seen improvements which I've added 3 minutes ago?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have now changed it to your edit - and it works! Thank you very much :)